# How can I drop length of input from textarea length and cap both max limits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

How can I drop input length from textarea length and display words left?

Here is what I want to do:
total length for input and textarea 200

```
<input type="text" id="b" name="b" value="Hi world !" maxlength="50">
```

> Added 10 words in input.
>
> Now set textarea maxlength to 190.

```
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" maxlength="190"></textarea>
```

> and showhere how many Words left

Comment: Please provide details about what you want to achive.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Something like this:**

I was not sure if you also wanted to cap the input at 50 characters.

```js
let max = 200;
const a = document.querySelector('#a'); // input
const b = document.querySelector('#b'); // textarea 
const c = document.querySelector('#c'); // output

a.addEventListener('input', e => {
    //  update textarea max length
    b.maxLength = max - a.value.length;

    //  update characters left
    c.textContent = max - a.value.length - b.value.length;
})
b.addEventListener('input', e => {
    //  use this if you don't want to limit the input
    //  update input max length
    //  a.maxLength = max - b.value.length;

    // use this if you want to limit the input to 50 or less
    // (if textarea has more than 150 characters)
    a.maxLength = Math.min(max - a.value.length, 50);

    //  update characters left
    c.textContent = max -  a.value.length - b.value.length;
})

//  initial characters left
c.textContent = max;
```

```css
input,
textarea { 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  width: 50%; 
  margin:5px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input id="a" maxlength="50" />
<textarea id="b" rows="4" maxlength="200"></textarea>
<p>Characters left: <output id="c"></output></p>
```

Comment: thank you for reply it works good, but maxlength 50 on input doesn't work is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: I've uncommented the code in the textarea listener – please try again :)

Comment: :)) Thanks :) you made me laugh in a boring meeting  thanks again :)